# Как сделать отступы между картинок сбоку, чтобы убрать последние отступы?

Tags: css3, html5

[image]

```css
.section__gallery-title{
    color: #01353E;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    padding-bottom: 212px;
    text-align: center;
}

.section__nav{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.section__navigation{
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #242121;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18px; /* 75% */
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.section__navigation:hover{
    color: #00B2A0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.section__photo{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 768px;
}

.section__photo-gallery{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.section__photo-gallery + .section__photo-gallery {
    padding-left: 20px;    
}
```

```html
 <section class="section__gallery">
  <div class="container">
    
    <h2 class="section__gallery-title">ГАЛЕРЕЯ<span>/</span></h2>
    <nav class="section__nav">
      <a class="section__navigation" href="">ВСЕ</a>
      <a class="section__navigation" href="">ТУРИСТЫ</a>
      <a class="section__navigation" href="">ПРИРОДА</a>
      <a class="section__navigation" href="">ПРОФИ</a>
    </nav>
  
    <div class="section__photo">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-1.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-2.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-3.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-4.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-5.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="section__photo-gallery" src="image/photo__bg-6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]